# to create a dataframe from directory having 10 text files

Tags: python, pandas

i have 10 text files in a directory and each text files has random text data(no tabular form). im trying to create a dataframe out of it and each text file data should should be along rows but not columns.

i tried the code as in below image, but the datas are loading in multiple columns but not in rows. tough i specifies axis parameter in read.csv method still no luck.
can anyone help me this.

```
filelist = glob.glob('D:/Annaconda/Project/aclImdb_v1/aclImdb/test/neg1/*.txt') 

df_list = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in filelist]

neg_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1, sort=False)

test=pd.DataFrame(neg_df)

test_df['label']=0

test_df.head()
```

Expected: all file data's should be append in rows.

actual: all file data's are appending in 10 columns.

Comment: Leave out axis=1. The default is `axis=0`, ie along the index, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other approaches without loops

Raw data files

**d1.csv**

```
a  b  c
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

**d2.csv**

```
a  b   c
5  8   5
6  4  22
```

**d3.csv**

```
a   b   c
15   8   7
10  85  22
```

Pandas based

```
import pandas as pd
filelist = ['d1.csv', 'd2.csv','d3.csv']
test = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filelist)).reset_index(drop=True)
print(test)
    a   b   c
0   1   3   5
1   2   4   6
2   5   8   5
3   6   4  22
4  15   8   7
5  10  85  22
```

Using [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#storage-and-conversion) ([installation](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/install.html#install-dask))

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.read_csv('d*.csv')
test = ddf.compute().reset_index(drop=True)
print(test)
    a   b   c
0   1   3   5
1   2   4   6
2   5   8   5
3   6   4  22
4  15   8   7
5  10  85  22
```

Sources

1. [SO post for Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118604)
2. [SO post
   for Dask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762213)